# Invalid modified date while importing Libraries

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2007, document-library, export, import

We're trying to get backup of our website to archive site collection. While doing this, we did move all folders and documents without getting any problem but "Modified date" column changing to today date. My import settings are below that you could check if I should change anyting.

```
settings.CommandLineVerbose = false;
settings.HaltOnNonfatalError = true;
settings.HaltOnWarning = false;
settings.FileCompression = true;
settings.SuppressAfterEvents = false;
settings.IncludeSecurity = SPIncludeSecurity.All;
settings.UserInfoDateTime = SPImportUserInfoDateTimeOption.ImportAll;
```

Thank you for reply.

Comment: what method you are using export the site and import site? are you moving the stuff to different site collections?

Comment: Have you tried content and structure option http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1097

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE using .net libraries which are SPImport and SPExport classes. Basically exporting documents to local path, then importing them to archive site collection. Yes, archive is  a different site collection.

Comment: @AmalHashim I'm working on console application and it will work every week for move documents to archive site. Original site has more than 100gb and I don't thing this method help to me